# Python (Selenium) - How to save data from page 1 to the last page to the same CSV

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a web page that I need to scrape all the data from the table embedded from page 1 to the last page by using Python with selenium.

Here is the web site: https://www.ageofempires.com/mods

I need help on making the code go to the next page until it reaches the last one. The challenge is that instead of having navigation buttons like "Next" or "Previous", this web page has the numbered indexes as buttons to navigate through. So it's difficult to apply the HTML elements in the logic.

Also, how to save data from each page to the same .CSV file? Why isn't the column title saved in my csv?

Below are my testing code so far:

Page navigation test:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

# Use driver to locate information
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path = "C://Windows//SysWOW64//MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
# Using Edge to open the website
driver.get("https://www.ageofempires.com/mods")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

while True:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='pagination']/a"))))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='pagination']/a").click()
        print("Navigating to Next Page")
    except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
        print("Last page reached")
        break
driver.quit()
```

Opening a CSV and saving data:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mods-listing > table')
filename = datetime.now().strftime('C:/Users/username/Desktop/Output/ModsAll_%Y%m%d_%H%M.csv')
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Which line? Do you see any error?

Comment: I'm stuck at making the code go to the next page when data on this page is saved. Also I'm not sure how to save data from the table each page to the same CSV file. Ideally, I would like to combine these 2 code sections together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mods-listing > table')
filename = datetime.now().strftime('C:/Users/username/Desktop/Output/ModsAll_%Y%m%d_%H%M.csv')
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mods-paginav"]/ul/li[2]/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mods-listing > table')
with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mods-paginav"]/ul/li[3]/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mods-listing > table')
with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])

i = 0
while i < 89:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mods-paginav"]/ul/li[5]/button').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mods-listing > table')
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
            wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
    i += 1
else:
    print("This is the last page! ")
print("Finished... ")
driver.quit();
```

My logic is a bit complicated so if there is any better solutions I will greatly appreciate.

From web page 4, the layout of the page buttons/icons are stabled so I'm able to use a for loop. For page 1, 2 and 3, I have to scrape data individually due to the different button layout.

In order to keep saving data to the same CSV file, just claim the funtion with an 'a' option which means 'append' so data will be appended in the same file.